# These Functions should work but why aren't they? The compiler says Error: too few arguments

Tags: c

I'm a beginner C programmer  and i have a test in two days, i write a code using a file, and the error was "too arguments for `fscanf`", can any one explain this for me ? the code is attached

```
int main()
{
  FILE *fpt_in, *fpt_out;

  int x, y, sum;

  fpt_in=fopen("input.txt","r");
  fpt_out=fopen("output.txt","w");

  fscanf(fpt_in"%d%d",&x,&y);

  sum=x=y;
  fprintf(fpt_out"sum=%d",sum);

  fclose(fpt_in);
  fclose(fpt_out);
}
```

Comment: There are too many typoes in what you posted. Clear that up.

Comment: You're missing some commas in function calls.

Comment: The posted code isn't close to a valid C program, so that would be why you get errors...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `,` in your argument list of `fscanf` and `fprintf`. That is why it is considering 3 arguments and complaining about that. Try to understand the message what compiler gives you:

```
testFile1.c: In function ‘main’:
testFile1.c:12:14: error: expected ‘)’ before string constant
 fscanf(fpt_in"%d%d",&x,&y);
              ^
testFile1.c:12:14: error: too few arguments to function ‘fscanf’
testFile1.c:16:16: error: expected ‘)’ before string constant
 fprintf(fpt_out"sum=%d",sum);
                ^
testFile1.c:16:16: error: too few arguments to function ‘fprintf’
```

Just add a comma after `fopt_out` and `fpt_in`. Moreover change line 14 to `sum = x+y`.

Comment: ooh thank you! i don't understand the compiler well because I'm not a native English speaker,, Thank you any way :]

Answer (score 1):

There are many typos in your code, but the "too few arguments" is caused by these two lines:

```
fscanf(fpt_in"%d%d",&x,&y);
fprintf(fpt_out"sum=%d",sum);
```

Replace them by:

```
fscanf(fpt_in,"%d%d",&x,&y);
fprintf(fpt_out,"sum=%d",sum);
```

Comment: Yes i got it, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *fpt_in, *fpt_out;

  int x, y, sum;
  fpt_in = fopen("input.txt", "r");
  fpt_out = fopen("output.txt", "w");

  fscanf(fpt_in, "%d%d", &x, &y);

  sum = x + y;
        //^ = replaced by +

  fprintf(fpt_out, "sum=%d", sum);
  fclose(fpt_in);
  fclose(fpt_out);
}
```

This is untested code.

BTW you should check if `fopen` returns `NULL` (e.g. if a file does not exist) and take action accordingly.

Comment: The error was about a missing comma, Thank you for your help any way :D